# Get names from another table

Tags: sql, database

I´ve got 2 database tables like this:
Users: id|username|name|city....
Table2: id|car|color|FK_user1|FK_user2|....
FK_users are linking to table users->id

How can I write my query, that I get the following result:
car|color|username1|username2|...
BMW|blue|thomas|mike

Thank you

Comment: The tables you described do not contain username1 and username2. Are you trying to split username, or are the usernames equal to FK_user1 and FK_user2?

Comment: sorry, but I think, I´m too tumb too format this proplerly :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query

```
SELECT Table2.id, Table2.car, Table2.color, FK1.username, FK2.username
FROM Table2
JOIN Users as FK1 on FK1.FK_user1= Table2.id
JOIN Users as FK2 on FK2.FK_user2= Table2.id
```

Comment: Hi, this was it. I didn´t know, that I can have multiple joins on the same table.

Comment: Dont use so many joins it will increase your query execution time